# Map SQL Logon to a Database using transcript

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, dictionary, authentication

I have a database called PERDB, and I restore this database on daily basis from a dump server, the problem is that the database has logons that disappear (deleted) after each restore, and I have to re-map the logons to PERDB manually, is there a transcript that I can use to achieve this?

I will use it inside SQL Job or stored procedure to run after the restore is finished.

Thank you

Comment: This question is pointless unless you name your RDBMS.

Comment: What does that mean? name my RDBMS?

Comment: I did the following and it worked

USE PERDB; 

Go

CREATE USER HRlogin FOR LOGIN HRlogin ;

Go

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'HRlogin'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following and it worked

USE PERDB;

Go

CREATE USER HRlogin FOR LOGIN HRlogin ;

Go

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'HRlogin'